# convert date object retrieved from json document to string jquery

Tags: jquery, json, mongodb, date

I have this json result in browser from aggregation I've done:

```
{
'reportDate': {
    $date: 1424044800000
}
},
```

I have it stored in mongo db like this:
    'reportDate':ISODate("2014-11-17T00:00:00Z")
how to convert it in format 'YYYY/mm/dd' using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JavaScript you can format it like that:

```
var d = new Date(1424044800000)

var string = (d.getYear() + 1900) + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDay();
```

jQ does not have function that formats date, you would have to use a plugin for that. For example [this one](https://github.com/agschwender/jquery.formatDateTime)

If you are using jquery ui you can use

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dateString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this javascript worked great beside dhe day it is showing only 1(first) day for every registred date

Comment: Thanks sir, I just used getDate instead of getDay and it retrieved me the right day...